# Placeholder of input text on my react component is not supporting:

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have used this code:
Color is not showing

```
.class::-webkit-input-placeholder 
{
color: red;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some more code. It's impossible to debug without this less information. Most likely the error isn't in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems  **::-webkit-input-placeholder** is not the correct way to do it.

You should use it like this:

```
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: red;
}
```

Read more here: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp)

Comment: I'm trying to decide if it was copied from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp

Comment: @code lol seems like it is

Comment: Yes. I copied this from w3schools, -webkit-input-placeholder is not the correct way

Answer (score 0):

`::-webkit-input-placeholder` doesn't apply to every browser
 use ::placeholder

```
.class::placeholder{
    color: red;
}
```